# Как десериализовать xml в лист обьектов с типом интерфейса

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Нужно получить `List<IRule>` десереализовав Xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <processSettings>
   <processName>chrome.exe</processName>
   <location>L1</location>
   <watch>true</watch>
   <rules>
        <autoStart></autoStart>
        <noMore></noMore>
        <unExpectedCrush></unExpectedCrush>
    </rules>
 </processSettings>
```

При попытке десереалезировать

```
XmlSerializer ruleSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<IRule>), new XmlRootAttribute("rules"));
            List<IRule> rules = (List<IRule>) ruleSerializer.Deserialize(config.Rules.CreateReader());
```

падает ексепшн что не возможно создать сериализатор с интерфейсом.

Comment: Ну вместо `List<IRule>` напишите `List<Rule>`. Строкой ниже вы приводите к этому типу.

Comment: Это опечатка, мне надо получить не обьект Rule в котором хрянятся IRule, а именно List<IRule>

Comment: Создать экземпляр интерфейса _невозможно_. Можно создать объект класса, реализующего этот интерфейс. Поэтому вы _обязаны_ использовать какой-либо класс, а не интерфейс. А потом, после десериализации ничто не запрещает делать приведение класса к интерфейсу.

Comment: При десериализации вызывается базовый конструктор класса, а у интерфейса нет базового конструктора.